# Flow of loop not functioning properly

Tags: php

i have a code here that 
if the $cost <= $row2['cost_disbursed'], it will execute the if statement here
but, it still deducts the values even if it is less than the value

```
while ( ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result)) && ($row2 = 
mysqli_fetch_array($query_result2)) )  {


if ( $cost <= $row2['cost_disbursed'] ) {

    if ($cost <= $row['remaining']){

    $sql= "UPDATE project set cost_disbursed = cost_disbursed - '$cost'  
WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $sql2= "UPDATE budget set remaining = remaining - '$cost' where id='1'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
    echo "<script>window.alert('Balance successfully deducted!')
    location.href = 'disbursed-Page.php'</script>";
}
   }

else {
    echo "<script>window.alert('Balance is not enough')
    location.href = 'disbursed-Page.php'</script>";

}

}
```

Comment: Is `id='1'` a typo in the last query? Could this be related to the problem of a wrong query running? Other than that, it's difficult for us to answer the question without more details.

Comment: Instead of fetching 2 rows simultaneously from 2 database queries, you should join the queries. And then you would probably have no need for the `if` conditions either. This is bound to lead to a lot of headaches.

Comment: @jeroen how do you do that

Comment: We need more context for that: What do the current queries look like and what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @jeroen
        these are not from the same table

  $query = "SELECT remaining from budget where id='1'";
  $query_result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

   $query2 = "SELECT * from project";
  $query_result2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2);